# PHP/HTML: require_once(config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html, directory, require

just simple question here.

I placed `dashboard.php` at folder

```
pages/dashboard/dashboard.php.
```

But the error appears just like my question. Can I know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: have you include require_once("config.php");

Comment: Did you check both of  absolute and relative paths? Please update your question and share folder structure and your path with us

Comment: @MohitKumar yeahhh.. include. maybe be need to be like this ("../config.php"). you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pretty much explains what the problem is: `you are trying to include a file that is not there.`

you have to use this at `dashboard.php` page :-

**require_once("../../dbconn.php");**

Comment: success!! but why my dashboard.php suddenly looks like all .js and bootstrap is failed to load?

Comment: it will also used this path directory.

Comment: I didnt understand. can u give an example

Comment: have your problem is solved with .js and bootstrap files ?